# Team server 2008 r2 connect to visual studio 2012 with extensions added

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I want to be able to connect to Team Server 2008 r2 to the Visual Studio.net 2012 that I installed on my workstation today. So far I am having problems.

I am making this change since I want to upgrade all my .net applications to using Visual Studio 2012.

Right now all my solution files have TFS attached to them since I loaded the solution files into TFS previously using Visual Studio 2010.

I have downloaded the plugin for Team server to install on my computer and I am advised that the plugin is installed on my computer. When I am in visual studio 2012 and I click on toos-->options-->source control and I get no options to select.

Thus can you tell me what you suggest that I do to solve my problem?

Comment: Have you considered upgrading TFS to a version slightly more recent than a decade old?

Comment: The upgrading will not happen for awhile since I work for a school system that needs to watch every penny they spend.